# Need to convert php openssl code to python

Tags: php, python, openssl

I'm working in a personal project where I need to read a `p12` cert in Python3. For now, i need to use `openssl_pkey_get_private` and `openssl_pkey_get_details` equivalents from php in Python3, but i didn't found a way to do it

I have searched the web for the equivalent for python without a look.

The PHP code that i need to convert to python is as follows:

```
$complem = openssl_pkey_get_details(openssl_pkey_get_private($this->privateKey));
$this->Modulus    = base64_encode($complem['rsa']['n']);
$this->Exponent   = base64_encode($complem['rsa']['e']);
```

For `openssl_pkey_get_private` I wrote this code:

```
def openssl_pkey_get_private(private_key):
    detailed_key = RSA.importKey(private_key)
    return detailed_key
```

Above code gives an array with `a`, `e`, `n`, etc. But for `openssl_pkey_get_details` I have no idea about what to do.

Comment: SO is not a code conversion service. Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Added to initial comment